# Moq Verify that Method was called with any expression

Tags: c#, moq

I'm new to Moq and I'm trying to Mock my repository.

The method I'm Writing a unit test for is calling the repository like this:

```
var paymentState = _agreementPaymentStateRepository.SingleOrDefault(
                         s => s.Agreement.ID == agreementID);
```

I'm trying to set up my moq like this:

```
_agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock
         .Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefault(s => s.AgreementID == 1))
         .Returns(AgreementPayMentStateMocks.GetOne);
```

I pass my mocked repository to the class but the paymentState variable is null after the call is made. (I would gladely skip specifying the expression as well).

Any help is much appreciated.

```
public PaymentState GetPaymentState(int agreementID)
    {
        try
        {
            _log.AgreementPaymentStateServiceGetStateStart(agreementID);
            var paymentState =
                _agreementPaymentStateRepository.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Agreement.ID == agreementID);

            var stateToGet = MapStateToGet(paymentState);

            _log.AgreementPaymentStateServiceGetStateReturn(agreementID, paymentState.LatestStatus);
            return stateToGet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.ServiceException(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and the test:

```
 var paymentState = AgreementPayMentStateMocks.GetPayMentState();

        _agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefault(s => s.AgreementID == 1)).Returns(AgreementPayMentStateMocks.GetOne);

        var service = new AgreementPaymentStateService(_agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock.Object, _log.Object);
        var result = service.GetPaymentState(1);

        _agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock.Verify(m => m.Match(aps => aps.SingleOrDefault(s => s.AgreementID == 1)), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: put all code in here if you can, sometimes it's something you don't think could be causing the problem.

Comment: SingleOrDefault is not an extension method right?

Comment: @Ufuk, Its an expression passe to the repository...

Comment: By the way, instead of doing Setup and Verify of the same thing, you can put `.Verifiable()` at the end of the Setup, and just call `_agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock.Verify();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having a concrete predicate in the `SingleOrDefault` call, use Moq's `It.IsAny<T>` method:

```
_agreementPaymentStateRepositoryMock
         .Setup(m => m.SingleOrDefault(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<bool,PaymentState>>>()))
         .Returns(AgreementPayMentStateMocks.GetOne);
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank yuou ever so much!

Comment: How does this work? I didn't think static methods (Select/Where) could be mocked.

Comment: @DanRevell, I believe, based on comments above, that `SingleOrDefault` was a method on the repository, not the extension method of the same name